# Find class inside form validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

**Why I am doing it**

I have used jquery validation plugin but it doesn't show desired output when used with bootstrap select. Hence trying to create my own optional method.

**What I want to do**

I want to search the form ***called by FormValidation function*** for specific class name across all inputs, select, checkboxes & radio buttons. If class found then I'll do some validation for quality & values & if validation fails then I would include error class after that element only.

***I am here to get some help on searching the form called by FormValidation function for specific class name only***

**What I have tried**

I have tried searching classname using following but it's not searching as desired.

```
function FormValidation()
{
    if($(this).hasClass( "fns" ))
    {
       //do some validations & show validation output
    }
}
```

I also tried to get form id so that I can search elements of form by form id using `$(this).closest("form").attr("id");` but this is showing undefined.

Please tell me what wrong I am doing here.

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="EMPREG" onSubmit="return FormValidation();" onKeyUp="return FormValidation();">
   <input class="form-control fns" type="text" id="Rec_Name" name="Rec_Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    <input type="submit" name="Create_Profile" id="Create_Profile" class="btn btn-success btn-md" value="Create Profile"/>
</form>
```

Js Fiddle for reference https://jsfiddle.net/ttt/cc3r36h0/

Comment: can u update your code fiddle, so that it is easy to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***this*** keyword in your function refers to ***widow*** global object.

If you need to code inline events try to pass the this, and event keywords:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="EMPREG" onSubmit="return FormValidation(this, event);"
  onKeyUp="return FormValidation(this, event);">
  <input class="form-control fns" type="text" id="Rec_Name" name="Rec_Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  <input type="submit" name="Create_Profile" id="Create_Profile" class="btn btn-success btn-md"value="Create Profile"/>
  </form>
```

So your function will be:

```
function FormValidation(obj, evt)
{
        if($(obj).find(".fns").length > 0)
        {
            //do some validations & show validation output
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what I understood is: how can i get the form object inside the FormValidation function? The answer is: the obj element is the form itself. If you are looking for other let me know and it will be a pleasure to help you.

Comment: I am just trying to search particular class inside form validation function. thats all what i want.

Comment: Snippet updated. use: $(obj).find(".fns") to look for the elements with the class....